# Django Complex queries joining tables with filters

Tags: python, django

I am in need of some mentorship.
I'm watching all of the Django videos and reading the instructions on models and queries, and I lack some understanding on joins.

Below is my model series.  I am trying to write a query that returns a name from Member Name associated with a Position called "Commanding Officer", given a Unit.  In short, I'm trying to get a Unit's Commanding Officer.

However, to get there, I need to bridge Member->MemberUnit->ClassPosition->Position.

Here's what I have:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    home_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    cell_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    fax_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    Cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

class Position(models.Model):
    Position_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    Position_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    Max_count = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Position_name

class ClassPosition(models.Model):
    unit_class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    unit_position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    Date_effective = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Class: " + self.unit_class.class_name + "; Position: " + self.unit_position.Position_name

class MemberUnit(models.Model):
    Member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    Unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    Position = models.ForeignKey(ClassPosition)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Unit.Unit_name + " " + self.Position.unit_position.Position_name + " ( " + self.Member.first_name + " " + self.Member.last_name + " )"

class Unit (models.Model):
    HType = (
        ('HQ', 'IFT Headquarters'),
        ('JTF', 'Joint Task Force'),
        ('GEO', 'Geographic Theater'),
        ('SHIP', 'Federation Vessel Chapter')
    )
    Unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Hull_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Hull_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=HType)
    Parent_unit = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)
    Class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    Member = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through='MemberUnit')
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    City = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    State = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='')
    Zip = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Unit_name

class Class(models.Model):
    class_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    class_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name
```

If I can get an example of this kind of query, I believe I can roll with similar queries, using this by example.  I would appreciate any help I can get for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to see which MemberUnit objects have a Position_name of "Commanding Officer"? Edit: Or, given a Member, you want a list of MemberUnit's who's ClassPosition's Position_name is "Commanding Officer"?

Comment: thank you.  Please reverse this.  Given a unit, I need the unit's "Commanding Officer".  Thank you so much.

Comment: @acree123 Given a Unit object? Because you didn't upload the "Unit" model. Would you be able to update your post to include the "Unit" model?

Comment: SOrry about that, thought I got them all.  It's up there now.  Thanks much

Comment: No problem. Unit has a ForeignKey with Class. Can you upload the Class model as well, or do you want us to access the Unit's "Commanding Officer" by going through Member ManyToManyField?

Comment: I submit myself to your best judgement.  I added Class as well. I'm going to perform two things:  1. In a page referencing the unit, list the commanding officer.  2. In a page listing all units in a table, I'm going to show the unit's commanding officer in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be the situation you are searching.
Try this; not tested;

```
unit_object = unit object which you already have;
member_unit = MemberUnit.objects.filter(unit=unit_object, Position__unit_position=Position.objects.get(Position_name='Commanding Officer'))
```

Here you can do a forloop and get all the members name;

```
for members in member_unit:
   print members.Member.first_name
```

or you can fetch a list of member names like;

```
member_names = MemberUnit.objects.filter(unit=unit_object, Position__unit_position=Position.objects.get(Position_name='Commanding Officer')).values_list('Member__first_name', flat=True)
```